# How do I get an VIDEO from a WIA camera?

Tags: c#, windows-xp, camera, wia

I'm developing small app in C# 3.5 for Windows XP that will automatically download images and video from a camera to a PC, on camera plug-in via USB.
I have a Canon ixus 50 camera and I figure out how to get images from that camera to the PC, but I just can't figure out how to get/download AVI format videos.  Can someone help me please?
It's true that I'm using WIA 2.0, but it seems to be working for now.  :)

Comment: I've experienced the same problem... I can see images (as IItems on the Device.Items collection) but not video. Video items do not appear to be available in any of the collections. I am using C# WIA 2.0 on Win7 64, against a CANON EOS 550D. I am starting to come to the same conclusion as the above poster - that this isn't possible with WIA?

Answer (score 1):

I have never ever managed to get WIA properly working.

Sometimes it worked almost fine for photos but there was no video.
Some other times it would never work on my customers' PCs (same camera, same PC specs).

Finally I completely gave WIA up and managed to create my custom control based on DirectX.

### What I've found

1. Using Expression SDK to get image/video: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework-4
2. DirectShow: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18511/Webcam-using-DirectShow-NET.
3. DirectX Capture (AVI): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library.

### Keep in mind

1. It's really easy to work with. Requires some Expression (SDK) DLL and for that it will work only in x86 and you will have to set your app from AnyCPU or x64 to x86. Period.
2. Works really fine but this is more to static pics.
3. Never tested but looks really close to your needs. Can't say if it works but I'll go that way for testing, at least.

#### My thoughts

WIA is rather simple and easy. I've used it on Delphi and Clarion software (both are native Win32). It's somewhat fine but nowadays WIA is not the way to go.

Many webcams simply won't work with WIA and you'll have to tell your customers to change their webcam to a strangly-named chinese/korean/wtf brand just to keep your app working.

Try the last option. At least, download and run the code.

Hope it helps.